# how to handle a timer which run a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I want to call a method after every 10 seconds.my method has thread. application crashes with this code.kindly suggest me any solution

```
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimerTask myTimerTask = new MyTimerTask();

        // to start
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(myTimerTask, 8000, 15000); // (timertask,delay,period)
```

now MyTimerTask activity class.

```
    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        CheckMsgs();
    }
}
```

and Checkmethod contains

```
    private void CheckMsgs() {
     showProgressDialog();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            msgList = DManager.getConversation(SenderID, reciverID, Url_Settings.conversation_Url);
            // Log.d("TAG", "msglist" + msgList.size());
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    cancelDialog();
                    if (msgList != null) {
                        Collections.reverse(msgList);
                        adapter = new MsgsAdatper(ConversationActivity.this, msgList);
                        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
                        if (msgList.size() > 5) {
                            listview.setSelection(msgList.size() - 1);
                        }
                         cancelDialog();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No record is found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }).start();
}
```

log

```
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733): FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:114)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:114)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at android.app.AlertDialog.<init>(AlertDialog.java:98)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at android.app.ProgressDialog.<init>(ProgressDialog.java:77)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at com.eAlimTech.nikahapp.ConversationActivity.showProgressDialog(ConversationActivity.java:483)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at com.eAlimTech.nikahapp.ConversationActivity.CheckMsgs(ConversationActivity.java:248)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at com.eAlimTech.nikahapp.ConversationActivity.access$9(ConversationActivity.java:247)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at com.eAlimTech.nikahapp.ConversationActivity$MyTimerTask.run(ConversationActivity.java:641)
06-21 18:15:03.993: E/AndroidRuntime(24733):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

Comment: @shylendra now I have edit with the log cat

Answer (score 0):

I consider that your variable `mHandler` define thread does not have `Looper` inside it. Redefinition it in UI thread will help in your situation i think.